# Problema com o Utf 8 em leitura de arquivo txt

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou usando a seguinte diretiva para leitura de arquivos txt, porém os textos estão saindo quebrados.

http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/6aG4x/

Comment: Qual seu editor de programação ? Está salvando em qual charset ?

Comment: uso eclipse mesmo.

Comment: No Eclipse ao salvar o arquivo ou em outra opção de SAVE deve ter pra salvar como UTF-8

Comment: Acho que fica em Windows > Preferences, no menu esquerdo vá até Web, HTML FILES e na direita escolha o Encoding que tenha: UNICODE(UTF-8)

Comment: Mude para `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >` pra ver se resolve. Se resolver, é exatamente o que o @Zoom falou.

Comment: não resolveu, @Zoom não encontrei a opção ao chegar em files na direita nao tem nada referente a isso.

Comment: encontrei, setei mas não funcionou...

Comment: Coloque a parte do HTML que tem a string com erro para vermos se não tem algum problema adicional no seu código.

Comment: acho que o problema é porque estou lendo arquivo txt, e jogando em uma string... testei um texto qualquer no html e funcionou, alguma solução pra javascript?

Comment: creio que vou ter que abrir outro tópico, pois estou usando uma diretiva no angular pra fazer a leitura, mas veja o código que to usando: http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/6aG4x/

Comment: Sugeriria você [edit] essa pergunta e por todas as condições reais do código com problema, aproveitando que ninguém respondeu nada ainda. Coloque todos os detalhes e o código na própria pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, agora ficou mais fácil =]

Você pode tentar o seguinte, fiz aqui no jsfiddle e funcionou.

Nesta linha:

```
reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
```

Substitui por esta:

```
reader.readAsBinaryString((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0], 'UTF-8');
```

Tenta verificar se funciona

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou bem ai?

Answer (score -2):

Bom,
Antes de mais nada, no banco de dados está com charset UTF=8 também?
Se sim, pode ser a codificação do arquivo html (como os colegas dos comentários disseram), mas pode ser também a codificação da conexão com o banco de dados.
Já tive problemas com a segunda situação acima, e no meu caso foi resolvido utilizando-se as seguintes consultas logo após conectar ao banco de dados:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
SET character_set_connection=utf8
SET character_set_client=utf8;
SET character_set_results=utf8
```

Veja se isso te ajuda.

Só um detalhe, com estas consultas acima, os acentos e demais caracteres especiais, teoricamente, vão ser salvos e lidos corretamente no banco de dados, então os registros que estiverem com estes símbolos ��, precisarão ser corrigidos manualmente, ou através de alguma procedure.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: acabei de editar a pergunta...